# Why is IntelliJ highlighting errors in one project, but not another?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ 13 and the Scala plugin. In one project if I make an obvious type error I get a visual indication, like this:

[image]

But I just started a new project and a similar thing is not highlighted, even after I compile.

[image]

I'm giving a presentation on some Scala code and I'd like it if the type errors highlighted like in the first one, but I have no idea where the setting is.

Comment: Type aware highlighting? This can be toggled in the right part of the status bar at the bottom.

Comment: useful qurstion, this really happens from time to time even on a running projects..

Comment: ziggystar, that was it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One reason could be that the level of highlighting is set to a lower setting. Check your lower right corner for a button which adjusts this setting with a slider. It looks like (at least to me) a policeman face :)

Another thing is that you might not have declared what additional languages you're using besides the primary one. You can configure this in the project settings.

Also if you are using a tool to build a project (like Maven for example) try rebuilding or reimporting your project.

edit: One last thing. Make sure IDEA isn'currently reindexing or running some background tasks, this really messes up code correction.

Comment: It was the "type aware highlighting" button, which was right next to that setting you mention in the lower right.  I never noticed those settings down there. Thanks.

Comment: I had a similar issue and discovered that I had 2 modules pointing to the same sources in 'Project structure'